# Getting List of Functions Available in `func` for SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I current use SQLAlchemy and rely heavily on `func` from

`from sqlalchemy import func`

Unfortunately, I am only aware of

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/functions.html

in terms of documentation for the types of functions you can use.

For instance, you can use `func.timediff` in `MySQL` but this is not documented (I believe). How can I find a list of possible functions for `MySQL`? I have already tried `dir(func)` but that does not seem to return helpful results.

Comment: You cannot. `func` will generate anything you give to it, and will send it to the database engine for execution.